# Change vim-t background color

Tags: color, context, backgrounds, t-vim

do you have any idea how to change code snippet's background color? I'm using vim-t (\definevimtyping..) and context. In vim documentation I found only how to change background color of highlighted lines, but I'd love to have whole code snippet with background.

I tried using /framed but it just broke code formatting. (I'm newbie)

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

definition:

```
\definevimtyping [JAVA]  [
        syntax=java,
        lines=split,
        option=hyphenated,
        align=hyphenated,
        style={\switchtobodyfont[small,tt]}
]
```

used:

```
\startJAVA[numbering=yes]

public class LocationCoordinate2D {
    private Double longitude; // zemepisná dĺžka
    private Double latitude; // zemepisná šírka

    public LocationCoordinate2D(double longitude, double latitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public LocationCoordinate2D getNewLocation(double bearing, double distance) {
        double brng = Math.toRadians(bearing); // smer v radiánoch
        final int R = 6371; // polomer Zeme v kilometroch
        double lat1 = Math.toRadians(latitude);
        double lon1 = Math.toRadians(longitude);
        double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(distance/R) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(distance/R) * Math.cos(brng));
        double lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(distance/R)*Math.cos(lat1), Math.cos(distance/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));

        return new LocationCoordinate2D(Math.toDegrees(lon2), Math.toDegrees(lat2));
    }
}

\stopJAVA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `textbackground` environment to add a colored background behind the code block.

Before you can use the mechanism you have create a new instance with the `\definetextbackground` command where you set `location=paragraph` to enclose the complete code block in the frame.

The new `textbackground` instance is than applied to the code block with the `before` and `after` keys of the `\definevimtyping` or `\setupvimtyping` commands.

```
\usemodule[vim]

\definetextbackground
  [VerbatimBackground]
  [location=paragraph,
   frame=off,
   backgroundcolor=lightgray,
   topoffset=.25ex,
   bottomoffset=.25ex,
   leftoffset=.5ex]

\definevimtyping
  [JAVA]
  [syntax=java,
   lines=split,
   option=hyphenated,
   align=hyphenated,
   style=smalltype,
   before=\startVerbatimBackground,
   after=\stopVerbatimBackground]

\starttext

\startJAVA[numbering=yes]
public class LocationCoordinate2D {
    private Double longitude; // zemepisná dĺžka
    private Double latitude; // zemepisná šírka

    public LocationCoordinate2D(double longitude, double latitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public LocationCoordinate2D getNewLocation(double bearing, double distance) {
        double brng = Math.toRadians(bearing); // smer v radiánoch
        final int R = 6371; // polomer Zeme v kilometroch
        double lat1 = Math.toRadians(latitude);
        double lon1 = Math.toRadians(longitude);
        double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(distance/R) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(distance/R) * Math.cos(brng));
        double lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(distance/R) * Math.cos(lat1), Math.cos(distance/R) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2));

        return new LocationCoordinate2D(Math.toDegrees(lon2), Math.toDegrees(lat2));
    }
}
\stopJAVA

\stoptext
```

Produces:

[image: Typing environment output]