# ConTeXt: Line numbering with background

Tags: context, backgrounds

I'm not sure how to combine line numbering with a background in a `typing` environment.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Desired Output]

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying:

```
\starttext
\startbackground[frame=on,background=off]
  \startlinenumbering
    \starttyping
Phasellus neque orci, porta a, aliquet quis, semper a, massa.
Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.
In id erat non orci commodo lobortis.
    \stoptyping
  \stoplinenumbering
\stopbackground
\stoptext
```

When I compile this, I get typing in a background, but no line numbers:

[image]

However, if I remove the `background` from the block line numbers appear as expected.

I can get essentially what I want with the `framedtext` environment but then I can't break across pages:

```
\starttext
\startframedtext[frame=on,background=off,width={\hsize},frameoffset=2em]
  \startlinenumbering
    \starttyping
Phasellus neque orci, porta a, aliquet quis, semper a, massa.
Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.
In id erat non orci commodo lobortis.
    \stoptyping
  \stoplinenumbering
\stopframedtext
\stoptext
```

[image]

I can also get line numbers to show up if I wrap the text in a `textbackground`, but then I'm not able to get the background to extend around the line numbers:

```
\starttext
\definetextbackground
  [MyBackground]
  [framecolor=black,
   location=always,
   background=off]
\starttextbackground[MyBackground]
  \startlinenumbering
    \starttyping
Phasellus neque orci, porta a, aliquet quis, semper a, massa.
Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.
In id erat non orci commodo lobortis.
    \stoptyping
  \stoplinenumbering
\stoptextbackground
\stoptext
```

[image]

Is there any way to achieve the result in the first image such that the typing can break across pages?

Comment: Do you really need `\starttyping .. \stoptyping`? If you want a typewriter font, `\tt` should suffice. Typing environments are for verbatim text.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I need syntax highlighting and the other typing environment features.

Comment: I think you could use the `vim` module by Aditya Mahajan instead. See an example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537289/change-vim-t-background-color

Comment: I was originally using the vim module and had the same problem. I posed the question about the `typing` environment because I thought it would have a wider reach.

Comment: `\setuplinenumbering[location=text]`?

Comment: No luck. To clarify further on the subject of `typing`, the problem doesn't even depend on the `typing` environment at all; just wrapping `\input{knuth}` in a `linenumbering` and a `background` has the same issue. Also, putting the `linenumbering` outside of the `background` instead of inside doesn't fix the issue either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119135/discussion-between-jairo-a-del-rio-and-butterwagon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the record, the following works:

```
\starttext
\setuplinenumbering[location=text]
\definetextbackground
  [MyBackground]
  [framecolor=black,
   location=always,
   background=off]
\startMyBackground
\startlinenumbering
%For testing only
\dorecurse{2}{\typefile{\jobname.tex}}
\stoplinenumbering
\stopMyBackground
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've done some additional digging through manuals and examples and I found a  solution using MetaPost. This provides a lot of flexibility at the cost of being more difficult to understand.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{MyMPBackground}
  begingroup; save lftbdry, rtbdry, parframe;
  for i=1 upto nofmultipars :
      path lftbdry, rtbdry, parframe;
      rtbdry := rightboundary multipars[i];
      lftbdry := (leftboundary multipars[i])
        shifted (-36pt, 0);
      parframe := point 0 of lftbdry
                --point 1 of lftbdry
                --point 0 of rtbdry
                --point 1 of rtbdry
                --cycle;
      draw parframe;
  endfor;
  endgroup;
\stopuseMPgraphic
\starttext
\definetextbackground
  [MyBackground]
  [location=paragraph,
    mp=MyMPBackground,
    frame=off]
\startlinenumbering
  \starttextbackground[MyBackground]
    \typefile[option=context]{\jobname.mkiv}
  \stoptextbackground
\stoplinenumbering
\stoptext
```

[image: Sample Code]